# solution to non linear correlations in glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear, generalized-additive-model

I'm doing a glm to test the relation between one variable with diferent climatic variables. Nothing is significative and I think maybe the problem is that the relation between the variables is not linear. 
[image: preliminars plots between variables]

Here I put the plots. It seems like there are groups, but the data is climatic values that repeats through the time, and I can't use it like a factorial variable. 
In case there's no linearity, I should do non-linear models like GAM?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say more about your model & your data? Have you plotted your data to see what the relationships look like?

Comment: BTW, this sounds like you're just asking about a particular function from some (unnamed?) software. Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I edit it. Sorry for my english, it's not my first lenguage and for me is very difficult to explain statistical issues in that lenguage.